# Converting IQueryable to list and iterating using foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, iqueryable

I am a noob to mvc.I am using a repository pattern with linq2sql using mvc
Just doing some test to get a clear idea everything around the it.
I am trying to output authors from author table.

```
public class AuthorsRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    private Table<BK_Author> _authorsTable;

    public IQueryable<BK_Author> Authors
    {

        get { return _authorsTable.AsQueryable<BK_Author>(); }

    }
```

in the controllers

```
public class AuthorsController : Controller
{
    private IAuthorRepository _authorRepo;

    public AuthorsController()
    {
        string connectionString = "";
        _authorRepo = new AuthorsRepository(connectionString);
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {            
        return View(_authorRepo.Authors.ToList());
    }
```

on the view part

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
<div class="item">
    <% foreach (var k in Model)
       { %>
        <%: k.Author_Name %>
        <%: k.Author_email %>
        <%: k.Author_phonenumber %>
        <%: k.Author_Website %>
    <% }%>         
</div>
```

When I try to run it I am having a compiler exception

"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'BK_Author' because 'BK_Author' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: `foreach (var k in Model)` is probably wrong. Did you mean `foreach (var k in Model.Authors)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page's model is somehow set to an object of `BK_Author` and not of `AuthorsRepository`. Set it to `AuthorsRepository` and access list of authors using its `Authors` property.

Answer (score 0):

In your View page, you could simply inherit something like this:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Authors>>"
```

or after foreach(var k in Model) you should case k to Authors like:

```
Authors author = (Authors)k;
```

Hope this help!!